# Use `-S` Flag by Default with `sudo`

Tags: terminal

I'm running inside an LXC container and would like to use `sudo` with a password. If I run without any arguments, I get `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`, and the solution to this was to run `sudo` with the `-S` flag in order to have password input read from `stdin`. I would prefer if I didn't have to use the `-S` flag every time. I realize I can create an alias for this, but I would probably prefer to edit some configuration in `/etc/sudo.conf` instead, if possible. I looked through the manpage and didn't see anything about it.

Comment: Why don't you have a tty present? Maybe sorting that out would be a better solution?

Comment: Good call. I saw https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3218 and thought it wasn't a feasible solution, but https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/1724#issuecomment-194416774 resolved it; I'll add that to my `~/.zsh_profile` and hopefully that will resolve my issue in the future as well.

Comment: Adding that to my `~/.zsh_profile` did nothing, and adding it to `~/.zshrc` makes it so I cannot exit at all (and runs infinitely many times unless killed). Any idea how to run it once? I can post another question if that makes sense.

Comment: I'd suggest adding what you have tried to this question.